# How to add event to calendar from an email automatically using json ld schema markup in the email?

Tags: google-calendar-api, html-email, schema.org, json-ld, pardot

Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently working on a project where the event details should be added to the recipient's calendar when recieved the email with event details according to schema markup.
But it is not getting added.

More Info:

- The email sending application is Pardot(Marketing automation tool from salesforce)
- The script tag is enclosed in  tag because the tool(Pardot) will alter the URLs in the email for tracking purposes if not enclosed in

Please help me in getting this issue resolved.

Thank you

I got the reference from google doc https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation and have built the email according to this.

I have done the settings needed in gmail to add invite from email automatically.

Below is the email code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>

<body style="background-color: #F2F2F4; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
<blockquote>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "Concert",
          "startDate": "2023-04-12T09:00-07:00",
          "endDate": "2023-04-12T17:00-07:00",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Concert Hall",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "123 Main St.",
              "addressLocality": "Arizona",
              "addressRegion": "CA",
              "postalCode": "12345",
              "addressCountry": "US"
            }
          },
          "description": "Concert event series 1.",
          "url": "https://www.org.com/event",
          "organizer": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Org Name",
            "url": "https://www.org.com"
          }
        }
        </script>
  </blockquote>

  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="rounded" pardot-data="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 40px 20px; border-radius: 20px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);" valign="top"><h1 style="font-family:'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size:38px; line-height:42px; color:#10134A; font-weight:500; padding:0px; margin:0;">Concert Confirmation Email With invite!</h1>
&nbsp;

<p style="font-family:'Inter', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:24px; color:#10134A; font-weight:400;">BOOKING DETAILS<br>
Concert Hall<br>
123 Main St.<br>
Arizona<br>
CA<br>
12345 - US</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<style type="text/css">p.calender-links-container {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
            }

            p.calender-links-container span {
              margin: 0 2px 0 4px;
              padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 0 0px 0 0;
            }

            p.calender-links-container span:last-child {
              border-width: 0;
            }
</style>
</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="margin: 0; padding:0px 20px; border-radius:20px" valign="top" class="">
          <p style="font-family:'Inter', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#A5A5B4; font-weight:400;">
            If you wish to be removed from our email list, <a href="{{unsub link}}" style="color:#A5A5B4; text-decoration: underline;">unsubscribe</a>.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?